How to merge 2 Function on Apps script
How to merge multiple function for apps script ?
I Try learn from google but I can't find solution
help me please, Thank you very munch.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Test1");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Test2");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Product");
var member = ss.getSheetByName("Member");

function doPost(e) {

  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
  var userMsg = data.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.message.text;
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    if (values[i][0] == userMsg) {
      i = i + 2;
      var Product = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); //Product
      var Data1 = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); //Price
      var Data2 = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue(); //Size
      var Data3 = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //Book Name

      var result = {
        "fulfillmentMessages": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Price : " + Data1 + " ฿"
        }, ]
      }

      var replyJSON = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      return replyJSON;
    }
  }
}

function doPost(e) {

  var diaflow = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
  var userMsg = diaflow.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.message.text;
  var valuess = member.getRange(2, 3, member.getLastRow(), member.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < valuess.length; i++) {

    if (valuess[i][0] == userMsg) {
      i = i + 2;
      var Product = member.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); //Product
      var Data1 = member.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); //Price
      var Data2 = member.getRange(i, 5).getValue(); //Size
      var Data3 = member.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //Book Name

      var result = {
        "fulfillmentMessages": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Price : " + Data1 + " ฿"
        }, ]
      }

      var replyJSON = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      return replyJSON;
    }
  }
}

How to merge multiple function for apps script ?
How to use multiple function because i use this code can run one function only.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Make the sheet a parameter to the function. Then you can call it with either sheet or member as the argument.
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Test1");
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Test2");
var sheet = ss1.getSheetByName("Product");
var member = ss2.getSheetByName("Member");

doPost(e, sheet);
doPost(e, member);

function doPost(e, sheet) {

  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
  var userMsg = data.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.message.text;
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    if (values[i][0] == userMsg) {
      i = i + 2;
      var Product = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); //Product
      var Data1 = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); //Price
      var Data2 = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue(); //Size
      var Data3 = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //Book Name

      var result = {
        "fulfillmentMessages": [{
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Price : " + Data1 + " ฿"
        }, ]
      }

      var replyJSON = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
      return replyJSON;
    }
  }
}


If var result not same how to if else example : var sheet show result template A but var memver show result template B

Execution log
4:05:02 AM Notice Execution started
4:05:02 AM Error
ReferenceError: e is not defined
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:6

I don't understand your question. As far as I can tell, the two functions are the same except one uses sheet and the other uses member in the same places. When you have identical functions like that, you define a function that uses a parameter in the place where they're different.

Obviously those function calls must be made from a place where e is defined. You didn't show how you call these functions, just call them the new way from that place.

Yes it correct because i fix place follow that code in google sheet but var ss1 and ss2 not same url how to use var ss1 show result template A and use var ss2 show result template B ?

That's why ss1 and ss2 are different variables, so you can use them to get sheet and member separately. I don't know what this has to do with templates, I don't see anything like that in the functions.

Ok thank you i understand it. but i run doPost(e, sheet);
doPost(e, member); can't execution pass on apps script.

How were you calling the function in the original script? e looks like an event from an event listener, so it would be something like addEventListener("eventname", (e) => doPost(e, sheet)); (replace sheet with member for the other event listener).
